# PHP - Simple HTML DOM Parser - How can I get data from a specfic table?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the info from this [url](http://web16.gov.mb.ca/healthcareers/searchjobs.jsp?&portal=1&row=1).

The info I'm getting is: city, dept, salaray, etc

Now I'm getting that info doing this:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $curl_moteur = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $web = curl_exec($curl_moteur);
  curl_close($curl_moteur);
  return $web;
}
    $url = curl_get_contents($url);
    $html_object = str_get_html($url);
```

And this is the function I'm using:

```
   function getCity($url)
    { global $html_object;   
    return $ret = $html_object->find('td', 86)->plaintext;
    }
```

This funcion is working great, but the problem is that, this function will only work for the exact current list of jobs (20 jobs), and it must be able to handle a number of jobs not equal to exactly 20.

Does anyone know how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that its not the difference of the number of jobs, but actually is that its running into an error in parsing the other list.

Comment: The `->find('td', 86)` is asking for the 86th `td` element. you probably mean to loop through each result of the `->find('td')` function.

Comment: I musn't find find the 86th td because if something in the web changes, my script would fail. I must find the data using another way.

Comment: Why pass the $url, then not use it, and then make $html_object global? There's so much wrong here that it's hard to know where to start.